# Is there a way to specify the isolation level in Kafka-Python consumer API?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-python

I am trying to write a consumer using Kafka-Python ensuring the exactly once semantics. The messages in the partitions are produced using a transaction aware producer. I read from the Kafka docs that I should specify the `isolation_level` to be `read_committed` so it would read only the committed messages. The thing is I don't see anywhere in the documentation of the Python client on how to specify this `isolation_level`. Any ideas on how to make my consumer read just the committed messages?

Expected result: Just get the transation committed messages 
Actual Result: The consumer reads even the aborted messages that look like this

```
ConsumerRecord(topic='tweets', partition=0, offset=504, timestamp=1557007360598, timestamp_type=0, key=b'\x00\x00\x00\x01', value='"\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000"', checksum=None, serialized_key_size=4, serialized_value_size=6)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python/issues/1707), `isolation.level=read_committed` is not supported from [`kafka-python`](https://github.com/dpkp/kafka-python) yet.

Comment: Alright. I realized that AIOKafka has this implemented [doc](https://aiokafka.readthedocs.io/en/stable/consumer.html#transactional-consume). Although async-ness doesn't really suit my application I am trying to make it work.